# Is there a C++ library just like eosjs?

Tags: eosjs, eosio.cdt, action, signing, library

I want to sign and send transactions (generally trigger any smart contract action) from a c++ external app. How can I do this?

If my app was in javascript, that would be easy since I know that I can use eosjs in this case, so is there an alternative for C++ or another easy method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

cleos is written in C++ https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/master/programs/cleos

You can try building off of it.